# Log4Net not Writing to the Database but Works Otherwise

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, logging, log4net

I have looked at many threads about this and I can't seem to see why my code is not working. I am logging to the console and fileappender but the Database logs never work.

My app.config settings are:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <threshold value="Debug" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
        <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="Info" />
      <file value="C:\\Sample.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <threshold value="Error" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <connectionString value="Connection_String"/>
      <commandText value="MyStoredProc" />
      <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
      <parameter name="AgentId">
        <parameterName value="@AgentId"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="6"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%property{AgentId}" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter name="customerId">
        <parameterName value="@customerId"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="15"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%property{customerId}" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@ErrorDate"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}"/>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="Console" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

The C# code is:

```
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T));
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["AgentId"] = agentId;
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["customerId"] = custId;
Log.Error(String.Format("Non fatal error: {0} ({1})", ex.Message, ex.InnerException), ex);
```

Comment: Bad connection strings?

Comment: Try turning on internal logging.  

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#troubleshooting
http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/

Comment: Why are you using `BasicConfigurator.Configure()`? As it says in the docs, _"The invocation of the BasicConfigurator.Configure() method creates a rather simple log4net setup. This method is hardwired to add to the root logger a ConsoleAppender."_. Use `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() method instead of the log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();

The XmlConfigurator will read your configuration and enable you to log to your database as configured. The BasicConfigurator will only log to your console.